# How to arrange the order of columns in a database of a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently added a `:title` column using Rails migration:

```
class AddTitleToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :microposts, :title, :string
  end
end
```

I noticed that it appear at the end when I do **user.microposts:** in the console:

```
=> [#<Micropost id: 1, content: "test", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-25 15:34:30", updated_at: "2012-01-25 15:34:30", title: nil>]
```

Is there any way of arranging the order of the title columns? Say, placing it right before the `:content` column?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Rearrange them in the schema and do rake db:schema: load

Comment: Won't work for reordering on production, and will be undone the next time you run a migration. That's why it says at the top, "Instead of editing this file, please use the migrations feature..."

Comment: When @NathanLong says "it won't work on production" what he means is YOU'RE GOING TO DROP AND RE-CREATE EVERY TABLE WIPING OUT ALL YOUR DATA.  Luckily I did this on my local environment and checked before pushing to production...

Comment: it should be reversible and placed in a migration script

Answer (score 15):

There is an `:after` option to insert the columns (no `:before` option unfortunately)

```
class AddTitleToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :microposts, :title, :string, :after => :content
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the previous one as it'll be reset when a migration is run.

Comment: AFAIK: compared to MySQL this doesn't work with PostgreSQL DBs